# How to invert a nested object of objects

Tags: javascript, object

I'd like to learn how to convert a nested object into a new one by rearranging this structure:

```
data = 
  { 
    centeredSlides: { 
      0: true, 
      1300: false 
    }, 
    somethingElse: { 
      0: false, 
      1500: 'aString' 
    } 
  }
```

So that it follows this structure:

```
newData = 
  {
    0: {
      centeredSlides: true,
      somethingElse: false
    },
    1300: {
      centeredSlides: false
    },
    1500: {
      somethingElse: 'aString'
    }
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab the [entires](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of your object and use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to build a new object from the `[[key, value], ...]` entry array. For each `[key, value]` you can iterate over the entries of the nested object and use the keys from that as your outer keys of your accumulated/new object:

```js
const data = { centeredSlides: { 0: true, 1300: false }, somethingElse: { 0: false, 1500: 'aString' } };

const res = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [innerKey, obj]) => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([outerKey, val]) => {
    acc[outerKey] = acc[outerKey] || {}; // grab the object already stored at the `outerKey` or create a new one.
    acc[outerKey][innerKey] = val;
  })
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the inner and outer objects in `data` with `Object.entries()`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

```js
const data = { centeredSlides: { 0: true, 1300: false }, somethingElse: { 0: false, 1500: 'aString' } };

let res = {}
for (const [key1, value1] of Object.entries(data)) {
  for (const [key2, value2] of Object.entries(value1)) {
    if (res[key2]) {
      res[key2][key1] = value2
    } else {
      res[key2] = {[key1]: value2}
    }
  }
}

console.log(res)
```